# How do i make new shell installed available for other user?

Tags: kde, users, gui

I have installed a KDE shell for a user. I wanted that same shell for other user on the same machine. Is there any way to do this or I just have to make the other user to install the shell using the following command?

```
sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop
```

Comment: How did you install it in the first place?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6fdufuKjc4 exactly like this

Comment: thats the only command... the one mentioned in the desc

Comment: Then it should already be available for other users.

Comment: option whether you want default ubuntu or KDE appear only for the user who has installed kde others have no option on log in screen

Comment: Are you using LightDM or KDM? Does the file `/usr/share/xsessions/kde-plasma.desktop` exist?